hint runStmt no output when redirected
Following this link and trying to stack run this module:
module Main where

import Language.Haskell.Interpreter

main :: IO ()
main = do
  _ <- runInterpreter
     $ setImports ["Prelude"]
    >> runStmt "x <- pure 42"
    >> runStmt "print x"
  return ()

there is no output when redirected from the command line:
user@localhost ~/hs-project $ stack run > 42.txt

I can only guess that - unlike in an answer from the mentioned post - the output of hint goes through pipes, because "print" runs inside the interpreter, doesn't come from the module.
This is the result of ls -l /proc/<pid>/fd.
lrwx------ 1 user user 64 31 mei 20:50 0 -> /dev/pts/4
lrwx------ 1 user user 64 31 mei 20:50 1 -> /dev/pts/4
lrwx------ 1 user user 64 31 mei 20:50 2 -> /dev/pts/4
lrwx------ 1 user user 64 31 mei 20:50 3 -> 'anon_inode:[timerfd]'
lr-x------ 1 user user 64 31 mei 20:50 4 -> 'pipe:[2705380]'
lr-x------ 1 user user 64 31 mei 20:50 6 -> 'pipe:[2705381]'


@DanielWagner Thanks. Is it possible to redirect?

Try having the interpreter flush its output before exiting:
_ <- runInterpreter
   $ setImports ["Prelude", "System.IO"]
   >> runStmt "x <- pure 42"
   >> runStmt "print x"
   >> runStmt "hFlush stdout"

or turn off buffering before generating output:
_ <- runInterpreter
   $ setImports ["Prelude", "System.IO"]
   >> runStmt "hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering"
   >> runStmt "x <- pure 42"
   >> runStmt "print x"

Both approaches seemed to work for me.
